Determining the Plane for a Given Point and Line Using the Equation of a Plane
I was working on an exercise following an example that required exactly what I had to do as well, but I encountered some difficulties.
Below, I have indicated 2 titles, the first one is the example I was following, the second one is my attempt at doing a similar exercise.
In bold, I have written my doubts that I can't resolve.
Thank you very much to anyone who will help me :)
THE EXAMPLE I FOLLOWED
Consider a Cartesian monometric orthogonal reference system in space $S$. Consider the following line:
$$r:\begin{cases}x=1+\rho \\ y=-1-\rho \\ z=-1+2\rho\end{cases}$$After choosing a point $A$ not belonging to the line $r$, with positive altitude, then:
$(1)$ determine the line $s$ passing through the point $A$ and incident perpendicularly to the line $r$;
Infinitely many points $A$ not belonging to the line $r$ can be chosen. To facilitate calculations, let's choose $A = (0,0,1)$, then
$$\begin{cases}0=1+\rho \\ 0=-1-\rho \\ 1=-1+2\rho\end{cases}\Rightarrow \begin{cases}\rho=-1 \\ \rho=-1 \\ \rho = 1\end{cases}\Rightarrow A \not \in r$$It's convenient to determine the Cartesian form of the line $r$ and thus as the intersection of two planes:
$$r:\begin{cases}\rho=x-1 \\ y=-1-x+1 \\ z=-1+2x-2\end{cases}\Rightarrow r:\begin{cases}x+y=0 \\ 2x-z-3=0 \end{cases}$$

Determine the plane passing through point $A$ and the line $r$, using the equation of the plane system:
$$h(x+y)+k(2x-z-3)=0$$ the passage through point $A$ is imposed:
$$h(0)+k(-1-3)=0 \Rightarrow k=0$$ Let's choose $h=1$, and thus we obtain the equation: $x+y=0$. I think here we choose $h=1$ because substituting it into the equation of the plane system gives exactly $x+y=0$, right?
Determine the plane passing through point $A$ that is perpendicular to the line $r$, using the equation of the star of planes:
$$a(x-0)+b(y-0)+c(z-1)=0$$ The condition of perpendicularity between the line and the plane is $(a,b,c) = \rho(\lambda,\mu,\nu)$. The direction parameters of line $r$ are: (I think they are the coefficients of $\rho$ in the original line $r$)
$$\lambda = 1, \quad\mu = -1, \quad\nu = 2$$ hence we have
$$\underbrace{1}_a \cdot (x) \underbrace{-1}_b \cdot (y) \underbrace{2}_c \cdot (z-1) = 0 \Rightarrow x-y+2z-2=0.$$
Conclusion: the equation of line $s$ is
$$s:\begin{cases}x+y=0 \\ x-y+2z-2=0\end{cases}$$


MY ATTEMPT
In a space with an orthogonal monometric reference, consider the following lines $r$ and $s$:
$$r:\begin{cases}x=2 \\ z=0\end{cases} \quad\quad s:\begin{cases}x=y \\ y=z\end{cases}$$ and the point $A(3,0,1).$ Represent:
$(1)$ the line through $A$ incident and perpendicular to $s$;
$A(3,0,1)$ does not belong to the line $s$, in fact$$\begin{cases}3=0 \\ 0=1\end{cases} \quad A \not \in r$$ Write the line $s$ in Cartesian form $$s:\begin{cases}x-y=0 \\ y-z=0\end{cases}$$

I want to determine the plane passing through point $A$ and the line $s$ using the equation of the plane system: $$h(x-y)+k(y-z)=0$$ Imposing the passage through point $A$: $$h(3-0)+k(0-1)=0 \Rightarrow k = 3h$$ Do I need to find a way to get the equation $x-y=0$? If yes, how should I do it?
I want to determine the plane passing through point $A$ that is perpendicular to the line $s$, using the equation of the star of planes:
$$a(x-3)+b(y-0)+c(z-1)=0$$ The condition of perpendicularity between the line and the plane is $(a,b,c) = \rho(\lambda,\mu,\nu)$. The direction parameters of line $s$ are: $$\lambda = ?, \quad\mu = ?, \quad\nu = ?$$ hence we have
$$\underbrace{?}_a \cdot (x-3) \underbrace{?}_b \cdot (y) \underbrace{?}_c \cdot (z-1) = 0$$Without having the coefficients of $\rho$ in the original line, what values do the parameters take? Is there a way to derive them?


when you arrive at $k=3h$, choose for example $h=1\implies k=3$

denote $t$ the line through $A$ and perpendicular to $s$, and $d_t=(a,b,c)$ the direction vector of $t$. Since $t\perp s$, you have $a+b+c=0$, moreover $t$ is on the plane hence $d_t$ is perpendicular to the normal vector of the plane. Can you take it from here?

In your first doubt, you can choose $h=1$ because if you multiply the equation through by any non-zero constant, you get another equation for the same plane. The solution points of the equation are not affected. As long as the original $h \ne 0$, you can multiply through by a constant to get any non-zero value of $h$ that you want. For the second doubt, you are correct.
